# Using VB.NET to create a Pivot Table on an Exported Document

Tags: excel, vb.net, pivot-table, excel-interop, late-binding

I have a pipe-delimited text file that I need to read, turn into a pre-formatted Excel document - complete with separate pivot table sheet - and save.

Reading the file and saving it as an Excel document are solved, but I can't seem to get the pivot table to work.  I've found a variety of tutorials online, but none are actually working for me.

Comment: I've reordered the arguments in the order they present, but I get the exact same late binding error.  New line is "Dim ptTable As Excel.PivotTable = xlPivotSheet.PivotTables.Add(ptCache, ptLocation, "Pivot")", where "ReadData" and "DefaultVersion" are excluded, as they're listed as optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up accomplishing this by changing the problem line to the below.

```
Dim Table As Excel.PivotTable = xlPivotSheet.PivotTableWizard(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase,
 Range,Location, "Title Here",True, True, True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've reordered the arguments in the order they present, but I get the exact same late binding error.

When VS complains and states: "Option Strict On disallows late binding", it is telling you that you are either attempting to reference some method or property on a object that it only can identify as type `System.Object` or perform an invalid implicit cast.

Now let's look at the problem code.

```
Dim ptTable As Excel.PivotTable = xlPivotSheet.PivotTables.Add(ptCache, ptLocation, "Pivot")
```

You previous defined:

```
Dim xlPivotSheet As Excel.Worksheet
```

Therefore, `xlPivotSheet` is not the culprit as VS knows it is type `Excel.Worksheet`.

The next logical suspect is what `PivotTables` returns.  While you were keying in that code, you should have seen something similar to this:

[image: PivotTables Returns Object]

Did you notice that nice little help that Intellisense gave you when you entered the code?  You did enter the code, right?  Or did you copy-paste an example from some internet landmine site that posts code with `Option Strict Off`?

Regardless, you now know that you should cast the result of `xlPivotSheet.PivotTables` to the `Excel.PivotTables` interface to enable early binding and thus use the `Add` Method without that nasty error.

```
Dim ptTable As Excel.PivotTable = DirectCast(xlPivotSheet.PivotTables,Excel.PivotTables).Add( ....
```

Recommended Reading: [Using IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx)